# how to turn on X switch for Maven in spring ROO

Tags: maven, spring-roo

I'm new to spring roo, I encounter below error when ran spring ROO command. Could anyone tell me how to turn on X switch for Maven 2 under Spring Roo Shell? Any hints would be appriciated. Below is the output,

```
roo> perform tests
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'repositories' (position: START_TAG seen <settings>\r\n<repositories>... @2:15)  @ C:\Users\686408\.m2\settings.xml, line 2, column 15
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building smartact 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ smartact ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ smartact ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ smartact ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\686408\workspace\jianming\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ smartact ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ smartact ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\686408\workspace\jianming\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests in error: 
  testFlush(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testPersist(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMarkerMethod(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMergeUpdate(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testCountAccountBooks(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindAllAccountBooks(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindAccountBookEntries(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testRemove(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindAccountBook(com.jianming.smartact.domain.AccountBookIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFlush(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testPersist(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMarkerMethod(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMergeUpdate(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindCategoryEntries(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindCategory(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindAllCategorys(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testRemove(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testCountCategorys(com.jianming.smartact.domain.CategoryIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindDepartment(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testCountDepartments(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFlush(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testPersist(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindAllDepartments(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMarkerMethod(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindDepartmentEntries(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMergeUpdate(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testRemove(com.jianming.smartact.domain.DepartmentIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindEmployee(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindAllEmployees(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFlush(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testCountEmployees(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testPersist(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMarkerMethod(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testMergeUpdate(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testRemove(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testFindEmployeeEntries(com.jianming.smartact.domain.EmployeeIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tests run: 36, Failures: 0, Errors: 36, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.959 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-31T15:29:40+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/26M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project smartact: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\686408\workspace\jianming\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: I managed to find out the answer by myself, just run mvn -X test under the project folder. However, I still can't see the root cause of this issue **Failed to load ApplicationContext**

Comment: Found out the root cause in surefire-report files. This issue can be closed